# ReacNative Error npm start

Tags: reactjs, react-native

estoy usando ReactNAtive en linux, npm version 4.6.
lo que ocurre es que cuando uso el comando npm start me tira unos errores y no inicia el servidor [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

logs:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/usr/bin/node', '/usr/bin/npm', 'start' ]
2 info using npm@4.6.1
3 info using node@v6.11.3
4 verbose run-script [ 'prestart', 'start', 'poststart' ]
5 info lifecycle React@0.1.0~prestart: React@0.1.0
6 silly lifecycle React@0.1.0~prestart: no script for prestart, 
continuing
7 info lifecycle React@0.1.0~start: React@0.1.0
8 verbose lifecycle React@0.1.0~start: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
9 verbose lifecycle React@0.1.0~start: PATH: 
/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/node-gyp-
bin:/home/daniel/AwesomeProject/node_modules/  
.bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/loc
al/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin
10 verbose lifecycle React@0.1.0~start: CWD: 
/home/daniel/AwesomeProject
11 silly lifecycle React@0.1.0~start: Args: [ '-c', 'react-native-
scripts start' ]
12 silly lifecycle React@0.1.0~start: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
13 info lifecycle React@0.1.0~start: Failed to exec start script
14 verbose stack Error: React@0.1.0 start: `react-native-scripts 
start`
14 verbose stack Exit status 1
14 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> 
(/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/lifecycle.js:279:16)
14 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
14 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:191:7)
14 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> 
(/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/spawn.js:40:14)
14 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
14 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
14 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:920:16)
14 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit 
(internal/child_process.js:230:5)
15 verbose pkgid React@0.1.0
16 verbose cwd /home/daniel/AwesomeProject
17 verbose Linux 4.10.0-35-generic
18 verbose argv "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "start"
19 verbose node v6.11.3
20 verbose npm  v4.6.1
21 error code ELIFECYCLE
22 error errno 1
23 error React@0.1.0 start: `react-native-scripts start`
23 error Exit status 1
24 error Failed at the React@0.1.0 start script.
24 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely 
additional logging output above.
25 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Comment: Ese mensaje no me dice mucho, ¿podrías poner los logs completos? Edita tu pregunta con el contenido de `/home/daniel/.npm/_logs/2017-09-28T23_17_57_209Z-debug.log`

Comment: ya agregue los logs

Comment: ¿Intentaste correr los comandos que te dice la consola?
    `sudo sysctl -w fs.inotify.max_user_instances=1024`
    `sudo sysctl -w fs.inotify.max_user_watches=12288`

Comment: si, ya me salio otro error

Answer (score 0):

ya arregle ese error ahora cuando lo corro despues que introduzco la url o el codigoQr o lo incio desde un dispositivo virtual me sale este error:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: 2]